# Dynamic counting of occurrences

Tags: r, count, frequency, cumulative-sum, cumulative-frequency

R newb. Small rep of my data.

```
TeamHome <- c("LAL", "HOU", "SAS", "LAL")
TeamAway <- c("IND", "SAS", "LAL", "HOU")
df <- data.frame(cbind(TeamHome, TeamAway))
df

   TeamHome TeamAway
     LAL      IND
     HOU      SAS
     SAS      LAL
     LAL      HOU
```

Imagine these are the first four games of a season with thousands of games. For the home team and the visitor team I want to compute the cumulative number of games played at home, on the road and total. So 3 new columns for both the home team and the visiting team. I would like to get something like this (in this case I am only calculating the new variables for the HOME TEAM):

```
    TeamHome TeamAway HomeTeamGamesPlayedatHome HomeTeamGamesPlayedRoad HomeTeamTotalgames
1      LAL      IND                         1                       0                  1
2      HOU      SAS                         1                       0                  1
3      SAS      LAL                         1                       1                  2
4      LAL      HOU                         2                       1                  3
```

To compute the first column (HomeTeamGamesPlayedatHome) I managed to do it with:

```
df$HomeTeamGamesPlayedatHome <- ave(df$TeamHome==df$TeamHome, df$TeamHome, FUN=cumsum)
```

But it feels over complicated and also I can't calculate the other columns with this approach.

I also thought of using the formula table to count the number of occurrences:

```
 table(df$TeamHome)
```

but it just computes the totals and I want the result at any given point in time.
thanks!

Comment: Good question, upvote for reproducable example and desired output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)
df <- df %>% group_by(TeamHome) %>% 
  mutate(HomeGames = seq_along(TeamHome))
lst <- list()
for(i in 1:nrow(df)) lst[[i]] <- sum(df$TeamAway[1:i] == df$TeamHome[i])
df$HomeTeamGamesPlayedRoad <- unlist(lst)
df %>% mutate(HomeTeamTotalgames = HomeGames+HomeTeamGamesPlayedRoad)
  TeamHome TeamAway HomeGames HomeTeamGamesPlayedRoad HomeGames
1      LAL      IND         1                       0         1
2      HOU      SAS         1                       0         1
3      SAS      LAL         1                       1         2
4      LAL      HOU         2                       1         3
```

`HomeGames` is created with `seq_along` iterated by row. `HomeTeamGamesPlayedRoad` is created with a loop checking the values in `TeamAway` up to and including the current game. The final row is the sum of the other two created.

Comment: It worked thanks! I was expecting something less complex for it but it does the work.

Comment: hi pierre. thanks so much for the help. Imagine I have an extra third column with the PTS scored by the home team and a fourth one with the PTS scored by the visiting team. How could I extend the formula to sum the cumulative points of the home team scored at home and on the road? thanks so much

Comment: It's better to ask a follow-up with another question. And add this question as link for reference.

Comment: Thanks Pierre. I just dit that. Please find the link here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32212365/cumulative-mean-with-conditionals

Comment: As you can see I tried to adapt your code for a slightly different calculation but could'nt make it work. I would like to use kind of the sumif function from excel

Answer (score 1):

A Loop Solution:

```
TeamHome <- c("LAL", "HOU", "SAS", "LAL")
TeamAway <- c("IND", "SAS", "LAL", "HOU")
df <- data.frame(TeamHome,TeamAway,HomeTeamGamesPlayedatHome=ave(TeamHome==TeamHome, TeamHome, FUN=cumsum))

for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {
        curdf<-df[1:i,];v<-ave(curdf$TeamAway==as.character(curdf$TeamHome[i]), curdf$TeamAway, FUN=cumsum)
        df$HomeTeamGamesPlayedRoad[i] <- sum(v)
}
df$HomeTeamTotalgames <- df$HomeTeamGamesPlayedatHome + df$HomeTeamGamesPlayedRoad

      TeamHome TeamAway HomeTeamGamesPlayedatHome HomeTeamGamesPlayedRoad HomeTeamTotalgames
1      LAL      IND                         1                       0                  1
2      HOU      SAS                         1                       0                  1
3      SAS      LAL                         1                       1                  2
4      LAL      HOU                         2                       1                  3
```